# What cause asp.net webforms to stop including the querystring in the action attribute of the form

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

When I request the Login.aspx page of my primary application

`http://app.primaryDomain.com/Application1/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=http://myapp.crossdomain.com/Home`

I expect the action attribute of the `<form runat="server">` to include the querystring from the request:

`<form action="Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=http://myapp.crossdomain.com/Home">`.

however, I only get the following:

`<form action="Login.aspx">`.

I've tried the following:

- compare web.config
- compare inherited web.config from the root of the site
- compare machine web.config from %frameworkversion%\config\web.config
- application pool settings
- application pool mode classic/integrated
- application pool .net framework version
- iis components
- making sure iis rewrite module is not installed

I am retrieving the page using multiple browsers with the same result.

Any suggestions on additional compatibility settings I may not have looked at are welcome.

Comment: Please tell us how you retrieving it.

Comment: @Win added information in question about request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things I did not do were:

- Compare the webforms aspx between the server and my machine
- Examine the aspx parsed source code or resultant DLL in Temporary ASP.NET Files\

Had I done ANY of those things, I would have discovered someone had modified the ASPX and hard-coded the action to `"login.aspx"`.

When this value is set in the ASPX, it is initialized in the control during FrameworkInitialize/__BuildControlTree.

When FormControl.Render finally gets a chance to run the Action property already contains a value, and you do not get the standard HtmlForm behavior that includes the QueryString.